# Serializers - HyperlinkedModelSerializer: Validar sus atributos (fields)

Tags: django

En `restframework`¿cómo podría validar los fields?

Estoy usando `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.
Sucede que tengo un modelo que especifica que por cada tipo de documento de identificación tendrá una cantidad exacta de dígitos, entonces quiero que se cumpla que la cantidad ingresada por el usuario sea igual a esa cantidad establecida.

```
def validate(self, attrs):

    documento_identificacion = attrs.get('documento_identificacion', '')
    documentos_identificaciones = DocumentoIdentificacion.objects.filter(documento_identificacion = documento_identificacion)
    numero_documento_identificacion = attrs.get('numero_documento_identificacion', '')

    if documentos_identificaciones.numero_digito != len(numero_documento_identificacion):
        return serializers.ValidationError('No cumple con la cantidad de digitos establecidos')
    return attrs
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Roberto. Por favor incluye más detalles de tu pregunta. Actualmente luce muy amplia y es posible que sea cerrada.

Comment: Quiero validar los fields (charfield, textfield, etc) por ejemplo el tamaño exacto de caracteres ingresados, verificar que cumplan con las letras establecidas, que estos fields cumplan con ciertas restricciones.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega la información que has descrito en tu comentario. Asimismo, sería bueno si mostrases lo que has intentado para resolver el problema y nos digas dónde te has atascado para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Cada documento de identificación tiene un cantidad fija de dígitos ejm: dni tendrá 8, ruc tendrá 11, entonces en base a eso el campo numero documento identificación tiene cumplir esa regla, y eso quiero validar.

Comment: Hola Roberto, no me queda claro porque quieres validar en el serializador. Tienes como opción hacerlo en front-end, como por ejemplo [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) o en el modelo como lo propone [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), sobre todo porque la misma documentación de DRF te dice que [confíes en la validación del modelo](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#limitations-of-validators).

Comment: Estoy usando backbone (ecmascript6), cual seria lo recomendable validar en el front-end entonces y no en el back-end?